# Select only records with region objects in MapBasic

Tags: mapinfo, mapbasic

I am writing a program that finds overlapping objects. I can't perform the AreaOverlap() function on objects that don't enclose an area (e.g. text, points) as the result would be meaningless.

**Is there a way to select only records that have objects that are regions?**

I have a function that checks whether an object is a region (see below) so I could loop through the objects and check them one-by-one but it would be more efficient to do this as part of a select statement.

**My example function:**

```vb
Function IsObjectRegion(ObjAlias As Object) As Logical
  Do Case ObjectInfo(ObjAlias, OBJ_INFO_TYPE)
    Case OBJ_TYPE_REGION, 
         OBJ_TYPE_RECT, 
         OBJ_TYPE_ROUNDRECT, 
         OBJ_TYPE_ELLIPSE
      IsObjectRegion = True
    Case Else
      IsObjectRegion = False
  End Case
End Function
```

**Update: my final, working code using Peter's method and my function:**

```vb
Include "mapbasic.def"

Declare Sub main
Declare Function IsObjectRegion(ByVal ObjAlias As Object) As Logical

Function IsObjectRegion(ByVal ObjAlias As Object) As Logical
  Do Case ObjectInfo(ObjAlias, OBJ_INFO_TYPE)
    Case OBJ_TYPE_REGION, 
         OBJ_TYPE_RECT, 
         OBJ_TYPE_ROUNDRECT, 
         OBJ_TYPE_ELLIPSE
      IsObjectRegion = True
    Case Else
      IsObjectRegion = False
  End Case
End Function

Sub Main
  Select * from TargetTable Where obj into temp1 noselect
  Select * from temp where IsObjectRegion(OBJ) into results noselect
  Browse * from results
  Close table temp
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create you function like you have described above and use this directly in your Select statement:

```vb
Select * From MYTABLE
   Where IsObjectRegion(OBJ)
   Into __THESE__HAVE__AN__AREA NoSelect
```

Pretty clever

Comment: Hmm that sounds perfect but it's telling me "Subroutine argument OBJ not defined." and "Unrecognized command: INTO". I'm using this code: https://gist.github.com/1510947

Comment: Time for me to go home now. I'll have another look at it in the new year. Merry Christmas and thanks for all your help!

Comment: Just noticed that you are missing a ByVal in front of your parameter: Function IsObjectRegion(ByVal ObjAlias As Object) As Logical

Comment: I've updated the code in my link above. I'm getting an error on line 8 "Cannot use an uninitialized object variable in an expression". I assume this means it's not passing in the value properly?

Comment: Do you get the error when you run the app? If yes, I think you might have some records without an spatial object. You can find these with this statement: Select * from MYTABLE Where not OBJ

Comment: Aha, you're right. I thought that "WHERE obj AND IsObjectRegion(Obj)" would fix it but I've just had to use two select statements instead. I'll edit my question to show my finished code. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

A simple approach would be as follows:

```vb
select *
from MYTABLE
where str$(obj) IN ("Region","Rectangle","Ellipse","Rounded Rectangle")
into q_RegionObjects
```